# Laravel query builder using hasMany output

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my syntax in blade file :

```
{{ $product->filters->where("filter_id","10") }}
```

And my output for this looks like :

```
{"3":{"id":7153,"product_id":"1","filter_id":"10","data":"Kajaria","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}}
```

And I want to extract only a particular data i.e. `Kajaria`.
I'm getting confused in writing  syntax.
I had already tried these syntaxes :

```
{{ $product->filters->where("filter_id","10")->data }}
{{ $product->filters->where("filter_id","10")['data'] }}
```

Comment: Try moving this into your model or a repository and then pass the result to your view as a single variable, collection or array. Your view shouldn't care about handling Eloquent models or running queries. It will help you keep things organised and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{{ $product->filters->where("filter_id","10")->first()->data }}
```

The thing is `$product` is a collection and you need to get property of just one object, so `first()` method returns first object from a collection which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to get a filter for a product. So, try this.

```
Product::with('filters')->where('filter_id', 10)->first()->data;
```